# Outputing getJSON results once and they update every x seconds without the results repeating over and over

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I had a previous problem solved on stackoverflow but the requirments of my project have changed so I need a new solution. To summerise I have a getJSON function that executes every 5 seconds to read for change in a JSON file. The problem I am having is outputting the data correctly. I want the data to output once but update every 5 seconds in case the user makes changes to the JSON file

Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('names.json', function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            $('#one').append(data[i]);
        }
    });
}, 5000);

</script>
```

This getJSON function allows me to grab JSON data and append it to the start of a div. Then I refreash the function so that if the JSON data changes then the data changes in the div. The problem is that the data repeats itself every 5 seconds.

The unexpected result after 15 seconds

```
453545Beady little eyesLittle birds pitch by my doorstep
453545Beady little eyesLittle birds pitch by my doorstep
453545Beady little eyesLittle birds pitch by my doorstep
```

The result I want after 15 seconds

```
453545Beady little eyesLittle birds pitch by my doorstep
```

If I change the JSON 11 seconds when the script is running

```
"two": "Eyes"
```

The result I want to get after 15 seconds

```
453545 Eyes Little birds pitch by my doorstep
```

Rather than the actual result I get after after 15 seconds

```
453545Beady little eyesLittle birds pitch by my doorstep
453545Beady little eyesLittle birds pitch by my doorstep
453545 Eyes Little birds pitch by my doorstep
```

Here is the JSON file I am using

```
{
  "one": "453545",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

Hopefully I have made this as clear as possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to decipher your question because there may be two different results of which one of them you're actually trying to achieve:

- have only the latest JSON result displayed (no change history)
- have only one JSON result per change displayed (history of changes)

The first one is simple and is as follows:

### *no history*: Clear results before displaying them

Before you append your newly received results you have to clear previous ones.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    });  

    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON('names.json', function(data) {
            $('#one').empty();
            for(var i in data) {
                $('#one').append(data[i]);
            }
        });
    }, 5000);

</script>
```

### *change history*: detect changes

Keeping change history has several different approaches:

1. First one has been somehow summarized by [rogal111](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11558182/75642). Although his solution may not be best especially when the format of your resulting JSON changes, because his code only work when JSON results have at least those 4 fields defined. If any of them's missing an `undefined` will get displayed and if any additional one is added it will be omitted.
2. A more *dynamic* solution is provided by [Trinh Hoang Nhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11558311/75642) that works with any JSON object's properties.
3. **The third possible solution** would be to call your Ajax URL by appending timestamp of the last change (`names.json/timestamp`) and if server sees that JSON has changed afterwards, it would send the object otherwise some default object would be sent over (i.e. `false` or `null`) which would indicate that no change has been made...

Comment: No, he want to out put changes thing, not just clear the result

Comment: @Robert Koritnik I am trying to achieve the first result in your question. The problem with your code is that it only outputs the last element of the JSON object. I need it to output all the elements.

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu: How do you know? **Quote** *so that if the JSON data changes then the data changes in the div* **Unquote** As I understand this may also mean that div content changes entirely not just gets appended by the new change... OP doesn't state specifically what they want.

Comment: @MatthewUnderwood: Edited my solution. It should be fine now.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik This works the way I intended it to work. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your JSON `version` tag and increment it each time you modifying JSON:

```
{ 
  "version": 12323
  "one": "453545",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

Then in javascript check `version` tag before append:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentVersion=-1;
     $.ajaxSetup ({  

       cache: false  
    });  

   setInterval(function(){ $.getJSON('names.json', function(data) {

    if(data.version>currentVersion)
    {
      currentVersion=data.version;
      $('#one').append(data.one);
      $('#one').append(data.two);
      $('#one').append(data.three);
    }

   });

},5000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an oldJson to compare with the new one. You will only out when they're different.
Ex

```
var oldJSON = null;

function compareObject(a,b){//Simple comparision
   for (i in a){
       if (!(i in b) || a[i] != b[i]){
          return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}

setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('names.json', function(data) {
        //do the comparision
        if (!compareObject(oldJSON, data)){
            for (var i in data) {
                $('#one').append(data[i]);
            }
        }
        oldJSON = data;; //Important
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: or just `if(JSON.stringify(a) != JSON.stringify(b)) { ... }`